# For External Data, what format is expected from a "Simple URL" endpoint?

Tags: lightning-connect

So we've got two options for external data objects in SalesForce - Lightning Connect (OData) and SimpleURL.

OData is very well documented. I understand how that one works. I cannot find any documentation about how we are expected to integrate through a "Simple URL" endpoint. Any clues?

Comment: I have the same question and am trying to get some answers from Salesforce. It looks like Simple URL can only be used in Chatter Files. Once I learn more, I'll post and answer.

Answer (score 2):

A 'Simple URL' data source is simply a file located at a given URL. The functionality allows you to have the linked file show up in the Chatter Files tab and feed. It's not related to the OData functionality at all.

See [the docs](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_files_simple_url_xds.htm) for a little more info.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note that OData is only available to connect with via Lightning Connect which isn't generally available yet. Until then you can only test it in a dev sandbox.

> We anticipate this product will be generally available in the November 2014 to January 2015 time frame. Any unreleased services or features referenced in this or other public statements are not currently available and may not be delivered on time or at all. Customers who purchase Salesforce applications should make their purchase decisions based upon features that are currently available.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=platform_connect_about.htm&language=en_US